# Fetching data for a specific row using Pig script

Tags: apache-pig

I have a csv file with the following data

```
characteristic, total/Percent 
Kids below 18, 24
mental problem, 30.7
physical problem 69.3
kids above 18, 40
mental problem, 41.20
physical problem, 59.80
```

Now using pig script i need to find out the mental problem percentage for kids above 18.

Can anybody help me in this ?

Regards,

Aditya

Comment: please post your exact csv data sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two ways - easy and hard

1 . Changing the structure of your csv file - currently you have data characteristic inside your data

```
   characteristic, Percent, Age group 
   mental problem, 30.7, under18 
   physical problem 69.3, under18 
   mental problem, 41.20, above18 
   physical problem, 59.80, above18
```

In that case you can just filter the required row

2. Write a custom loader that will do some preprocessing of the data. It's a hard way, but in case you can't change input structure it can be your choice

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Alexey, yeh after a bit of research i was also narrowing down on using a custom UDF.